# why is javascript onmouseover functions is getting called on page load?

Tags: javascript

I have a html page with a link and onMouseOver of that link I'm calling
`return escape(showToolTip())`

```
    function showToolTip(){
alert(document.getElementById('toggleFlag'));
        var text;
        alert(document.getElementById('toggleFlag').value);
        if(document.getElementById('toggleFlag').value == false){
            text = 'hide';
            alert('hide');
        }else{
            text = 'show';      
            alert('show');
        }
```

This function is getting called on page load and when I mouse over I get show. When I mouse out and mouseover again it shows up as 'show' but never calls the function.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't appear you're ever setting toggleFlag's value to false.

Comment: Im setting it to false on the onClick function I have for that link..under any case I think I should see the first alert on mouseover

Comment: Hmmm...  ignore my answer then because I've got no clue what your question is then :)  What do you mean by "the first alert"?  Do you mean, the first alert(document.getElementById('toggleFlag))?  Do you mean alert(doc.get(toggleFlag).value)?  Do you mean alert(show)?  More code and more detail might help a lot here.

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick = "getOrderDetail();return false;" onmouseover="return escape(showToolTip)"> <tr:ds text="${heat.millOrdNum}" />, </a>`

getOrderDetail function here sets the document.getElementById('toggleFlag') to false

Comment: What's your end goal with "return escape(showToolTip)?  You're trying to URL encode a method that doesn't return anything encodable.  And without the params on the method, you're never calling it - you're trying to encode the method itself, not its result.

Comment: My task is there will be a link with a mouseover and a onlcick functionality. On mouseover, I need to show tooptip with text "Click to show order details" and when clicked I should make an ajax call and render and populate the hidden div. On mouseover again, I need to show "Click to hide Order detail" and when clicked the div should not be displayed. My showToolTip funtion returns the text "show" or "hide"

Comment: Change `onmouseover="return escape(showToolTip)"` to `onmouseover="return showToolTip();"`, OR, make showToolTip return 'show' or 'hide' instead of alerting those values, and change `onmouseover="return escape(showToolTip)"` to `onmouseover="return escape(showToolTip());"`

Comment: I made the second change to return show or hide in the function but the onMouseOver still gets fired on load.

Comment: So you are actually getting alert boxes on the page load?

Comment: Where else is showToolTip called?

Comment: @Mahi - it seems you may need more assistance than bite-sized pieces of code will allow contributors to provide - perhaps you can post an abbreviated sample of your code as a fiddle?

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for your help. I will look for someother way of finishing this task. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that when you're setting your event handler, you're including the parenthesis on the method you wish to call.

Such as:

```
onMouseOver = showTooltip()
```

This causes the event to fire immediately and the handler to only be given the result of the method that already executed.

If this is the case you'll want to change your event hander by removing the parenthesis.

```
onMouseOver = showTooltip
```

As pointed out in the comments below, this isn't accounting for declerative event handling such as:

```
<div onmouseover="foo()">
```

which will not fire on page load.

Comment: almost downvoted you for this - you should really be more explicit here and mention that this is only true for imperative, not declarative, event handling.  i.e., `<div onmouseover="foo();" >` is perfectly acceptable and will not fire on load.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I've included that piece of info in my answer.

Comment: +1 for follow-up and a likely cause for someone, if not this guy.

Answer (score 0):

Again, per my comment, I have no idea what the rest of your implementation looks like, but you're never actually toggling the value of 'toggleValue' in your method...

```
function showToolTip(){    
     var text;             
     if(document.getElementById('toggleFlag').value == false){       
          // TOGGLE TO TRUE      
          document.getElementById('toggleFlag').value = true;
          text = 'hide';             
          alert('hide');         
     }
     else {            
          // TOGGLE TO FALSE
          document.getElementById('toggleFlag').value = false; 
          text = 'show';                   
          alert('show');         
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around your true and false. You are comparing a string to a js bool rather than the value inside the element.

```
if(document.getElementById('toggleFlag').value == "false"){
            text = 'hide';
            alert('hide');
        }else{
            text = 'show';      
            alert('show');
        }
```

A fiddle of what I'm seeing is here: http://jsfiddle.net/k7mJX/

Comment: definitely removed the downvote almost immediately - I was unaware that == vs === was a special exception for boolean values.

Comment: eh the answer doesn't fix his immediate issue anyway if he is getting alert boxes on the page load

Comment: For testing purposes, I removed everything. I only have a showToolTip function which alerts hello and returns hello. On the mouseover function i called it as onmouseover="return escape(showToolTip());". When i hit the url, I get the hello alert on page laod.